# Gitlab CI only compiles Cython on every other build

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cython

We're moving over to Gitlab and have set up a CI pipeline. It's mostly working, except that sometimes the Cython files get compiled and sometimes they don't. We can't figure out why it only works for some builds.

When it works, the log for the build_wheel job looks something like this (I've removed the irrelevant lines)

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.5.2 (e91107dd)

Using Docker executor with image python:3.8 ...
Pulling docker image python:3.8 ...

Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds//code/farmmap/.git/
Checking out c9e57baf as refs/merge-requests/3/head...
Removing .cache/
Removing codeclimate.json
Removing dist/
Removing public/
Removing venv/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache

$ python -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
$ pip install build cython
$ python -m build --wheel --no-isolation
* Getting dependencies for wheel...
Compiling farm/rasters/water_fill.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing farm/rasters/water_fill.pyx

gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/farm/rasters/water_fill.o -L/usr/local/lib -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/farm/rasters/water_fill.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

When it doesn't work, the log is mostly the same and the build appears to be a success, but when you search the log output for ".so", it only appears once, in the "Removing" stage:

```
Removing farm/rasters/water_fill.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

We don't get the "Compiling foo.pyx because it changed" followed by the gcc call. Why is this? Is there something we need to do to the cleanup in our .gitlab-ci.yml file so the build is the same every time?

Comment: setuptools build_ext has a `--force` option that might help you. It isn't clear what your "build" module is though, so I don't know if that would apply

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, but no luck. I think it might be due to gitlab reusing the docker image and not reinstalling our package. I think I need to make it do a complete reinstall every time.